# A Better Way to Solve this Factorial Problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, factorial

I had a problem that asked me to find which of the following is larger:

> ${2013 \choose 500}$ or ${2013 \choose 1500}$

Beneath is my proof. I think it is correct (though your verification and suggestions would nonetheless be appreciated). I haven't worked with factorials all that much, and am curious to see if it could be done any more swiftly. Are there easier ways to prove this proposition?

${\bf Proof:}$
$${n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
$${2013 \choose 1500} = \frac{2013!}{1500!(2013-1500)!} = \frac{2013!}{1500!\cdot 513!}$$
$${2013 \choose 500} = \frac{2013!}{500!(2013-500)!} = \frac{2013!}{500!\cdot 1513!}$$
Obviously, if $500!1513! > 1500!513!$, then ${2013 \choose 1500} > {2013 \choose 500}$ and vice-versa. Note that $\frac{500!1513!}{500!} = 1513!$, and $\frac{513!1500!}{500!} = 1500!\cdot(501\cdot 502 \cdot ... \cdot 513)$. We can rewrite $1513!$ as $1500 \cdot (1501 \cdot 1502 \cdot ... \cdot 1513)$. As both expansions $A = (501 \cdot ... \cdot 513), B = (1501 \cdot ... \cdot 1513)$ have 13 terms each, and $\forall a \in A, a < b$ for any $b \in B$, it must be that $\prod\limits_{a\in A} a < \prod\limits_{b \in B} b$. So $1513! > 1500!(501\cdot ... \cdot 513)$, so $500!1513! > 1500!513!$, so $\frac{2013!}{500!1513!}<\frac{2013!}{1500!513!}$, so ${2013 \choose 1500} > {2013 \choose 500}$. $\square$

Comment: Use the symmetry, $\binom{2013}{1500} = \binom{2013}{513}$, and the monotnonicity of the binomial coefficients until the middle. $\binom{2013}{1500} > \binom{2013}{500}$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What do you mean with monotonicity?

Comment: The monotonicity is $\binom{n}{k} < \binom{n}{k+1}$ while $k+1 \leqslant \frac{n}{2}$. It's essentially what your proof shows if one looks at it long enough. $\binom{n}{k+1} = \frac{n-k}{k+1}\cdot \binom{n}{k}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence $$\left\langle\binom{2013}k:k=0,1,\ldots,2013\right\rangle$$ is centrally symmetric and single-peaked, increasing from $\binom{2013}0=1$ to a maximum at $\binom{2013}{1006}=\binom{2013}{1007}$ and then falling to $\binom{2013}{2013}=1$. Since $500<513\le 1006$, we must have $$\binom{2013}{500}<\binom{2013}{513}=\binom{2013}{1500}\;.$$

Comment: Oh, so this must be related to the monotonicity that Daniel Fischer mentioned!

Comment: @Newb: Yes: the sequence is monotonically increasing for the first half and monotonically decreasing for the second half.

Answer (score 1):

$1006.5 - 500 = 506.5.\quad$ $1500 - 1006.5 = 493.5$.
$$
\mbox{Since}\ 493.5 < 506.5\,,\quad
{2013 \choose 1500} > {2013 \choose 500}
$$

Comment: I don't see the intuition behind this at all. How are you doing this computation?

Comment: @Newb The binomial is symmetric around $2013/2 = 1006.5$ (you can always use the generalization to real or/and complex values) where it's a maximum. As $1500$ is closer to $1006.5$ than $500$, it's clear that the binomial "with $1500$" is bigger.

Comment: Now it makes perfect sense. Thanks!